# Angular: Atributo não está sendo atualizado na tela, mas está no componente

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou usando a notação de "double mustache" para mostrar um atributo de um componente que está sendo atualizado eventualmente.
O problema ocorre porque os dados atualizam no atributo no componente, porém, ao usar os dados diretamente desse atributo, nada é mostrado na tela.
Código de como o atributo está sendo atualizado na pagina:

```
this.consumer.verificar(this.formData).subscribe({
  next: result => {
    result.registrosLidos = Math.abs(result.registrosAptos + result.registrosInconsistentes);
    this.resumo = new ResumoImportacao();
    // tentei igualar cada valor do atributo e continua nao funcionando
    this.resumo = result;
  },
  error: (err: any) => {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Já no HTML da pagina:

```html
    <div *ngIf="isVerifying; else container"
      style="display: flex; 
      justify-content: center; 
      align-items: center;">
        <mat-spinner class = "spinner-table"></mat-spinner>
      </div>
      <ng-template #container>
        <form [formGroup]="thirdFormGroup">
          <mat-form-field class="medium">
            <mat-label>Arquivo</mat-label>
            <input matInput name="arquivo" formControlName="arquivo" readonly>
          </mat-form-field>
        </form>
        <p><b>Validações do processamento</b></p>
        Tipo de arquivo (.XLS) {{this.resumo?.tipoArquivo?.includes('XLS') ? 'Ok' : 'Não'}}
        Leiaute do arquivo {{this.resumo?.isValid? 'Ok' : 'Não'}}
        Registros lidos: {{this.resumo?.registrosLidos}}
        Registros aptos para importação:{{this.resumo?.registrosAptos}}
        Registros inconsistentes:{{this.resumo?.registrosInconsistentes}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tente remover o `this.` de dentro dos `{{ }}`, e verifique se a variável resumo está no escopo do componente. Quando a variável é chamada pelo HTML não tem a necessidade de usar `this.`